# Não estou conseguindo recuperar o id de uma listview

Tags: android

Boa noite, criei um xml com um TextView para eu inserir no meu ListView, pois quero deixa ele personalizado.... Mas não estou conseguindo recuperar ele no meu metodo que esta dentro da class fragment? alguem poderia me ajudar?

Dupla.java (class fragment)

```
public void vectorOne(){
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

        final ArrayAdapter<String> listing = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.lita_personalizada_dupla_sena, //nao estou conseguindo
                android.R.id.txt_final, //nao estou conseguindo
                list
        );

        listArray.setAdapter(listing);

       //restante do code
}
```

Obrigado....

Comment: Não é dessa forma. Você tem que criar uma classe que extenda a BaseAdapter e nesta classe recuperar o layout customizado. O adapter vai ser uma instância da classe que você criar. Dá um pesquisada no Google. Tem milhares de tutoriais sobre isso: ListView custom layout

Comment: ahh entendi, ok

Comment: View view = act.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_personalizada_dupla_sena, parent, false);
        TextView texto = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_final);


Desta forma não estou conseguindo achar o id do meu layout